# How do I pin IE-based applications to taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, taskbar

My employer uses an IE-based application for timesheets, so I have to use this every day several times. I'm not sure what this type of application is called, but to get to it, I have to open a link in IE (works only in IE), which then asks me if  I want to open the application, so it seems it gets pulled from a server.

[image: Prompt in IE]

Then it opens an application that is clearly not just an IE website (it opens in its own window and looks like a regular windows application). When I right-click the icon, though, I don't see an option to pin the app to the taskbar, all I can do is close the window.

What is this kind of app, and how do I pin it to the taskbar? Or, if that's not possible, is there a workaround to open this from a modern browser instead?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but this begs the question: did you already query your employer's IT support staff?  I'm guessing that you wouldn't be the first person to ask them.

Comment: It could be what is called an "HTML Application", most commonly packaged as .hta files. These are web pages that instead of opening in a full browser, open in a compact window with only the title bar and borders. There are ways to open them in the full browser, but the default behavior is to run them in this compact window that lets them pretend to be local applications.

Comment: The other, more likely, thing is that this is a "Click-Once" application (common use of the .application extension). It's probably a .NET-based application. Why it has to be run from the website each time, I don't know: that's a question, again, for your local IT.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. After those pointers, I do believe it may be a Clock-Once application. I take it it's not normal/required that they must be loaded from a website each time? I have spoken to out IT about this, and basically got the answer that having to open IE and going to the website to get to the app is not too much to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments by @music2myear, I found out this is a ClickOnce application. There are a variety of plugins available for Chrome that allow opening these from within Chrome. I would imagine Firefox would have similar addons available. So this is a partial answer to my own question.

A simple [search in the Chrome Web Store for the term "ClickOnce"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/clickonce) yielded a number of promising results, and several of the plugins I tried seemed to work fine. One tip I would add is, it seems these plugins need access to all sites you visit, so if you only need access to a specific application from a certain URL, it is possible to lock the plugin down to only be able to access that site.